# Android Name of State Accessed by Arrow Keys

Tags: android, selector

Simple Question here, what is it called when a user uses the arrow keys to access a button?
For example when a user pressed a button, it's called the pressed state.

Furthermore how do I target this state when using a selector?
Here is my current selector

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#d7d6d6"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:color="#d7d6d6"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#d7d6d6"/> <!-- default -->
```

I want to also change the color when the user comes to the view by using the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the focused state or state_focused in XML.

To quote the reference:

> onFocusChange()
>   From View.OnFocusChangeListener. This is called when the user navigates onto or away from the item, using the navigation-keys or trackball.

Further down on the [same page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#HandlingFocus) you find how to handle focus change.
Hope that helps! :)